# Why does make recompile everything in this makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
#
CC=gcc
CPLUS=g++
DIR=HypeRvieW
GTK_LIB=`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -lGL -lfreetype
GTK_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
GLIB_LIB=`pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
GLIB_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
MODULE_EXPORT_LIB=`pkg-config --libs gmodule-export-2.0`
MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags gmodule-export-2.0`
LIBGLADE_LIB=`pkg-config --libs libglade-2.0`
LIBGLADE_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags libglade-2.0`
LIBMATIO_LIB=`pkg-config --libs matio`
LIBMATIO_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags matio`
FFTW3_CFLAGS=-lfftw3

all:  start_aux global_data.so librexistrado libmatlab.so libhrw.so libimg_format.so librawm.so tiff.o libelm libpca_emp libpca librqs libsvmPredict libwatershed libmajorityv_watershed libmajorityv_rqs libsmoothing libdenoising mainCopy_aux ayuda.o classification.o gtk-diagram.o gtk-plugin.o gtk-pin.o gtk-connection.o gtk-context-menu.o gtk-notification.o colors.o dialogUtils.o progressbar.o utilFunctions.o eventHelper.o renderHelper.o fileSystem.o openHelper.o saveHelper.o execute.o executeHelper.o  common_functions.o ground_truth.o histogram.o image.o interface_plugins.o main.o md5.o manage_files.o manage_plugin.o color.o editor_ground_truth.o editor_segmented_image.o menu.o signals.o window.o biophysical.o segalgths/FH.o segalgths/ETPS.o end
    $(CPLUS) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -o $(DIR)/HypeRvieW main/ayuda.o main/classification/classification.o main/classification/gtk-diagram.o main/classification/gtk-plugin.o main/classification/gtk-pin.o main/classification/gtk-connection.o main/classification/gtk-context-menu.o main/classification/gtk-notification.o main/classification/utils/colors.o main/classification/utils/dialogUtils.o main/classification/utils/progressbar.o main/classification/utils/utilFunctions.o main/classification/helpers/eventHelper.o main/classification/helpers/renderHelper.o main/classification/fileSystem/fileSystem.o main/classification/fileSystem/openHelper.o main/classification/fileSystem/saveHelper.o main/classification/execution/execute.o main/classification/execution/executeHelper.o main/common_functions.o main/ground_truth.o main/histogram.o main/image.o main/interface_plugins.o main/main.o main/md5.o tiff/tiff.o main/manage_files.o main/manage_plugin.o main/color.o main/editor_ground_truth.o segalgths/FH.o segalgths/ETPS.o main/editor_segmented_image.o main/menu.o main/signals.o main/window.o main/biophysical.o -Lmain/dlib $(GTK_LIB) $(MODULE_EXPORT_LIB) $(LIBGLADE_LIB)  $(GLIB_LIB) $(LIBMATIO_LIB) $(FFTW3_CFLAGS) -lm -lz -ldl -lglobal_data -lrawm -lmatlab -lhrw -limg_format -lglib-2.0 -lcrypto -ltiff -g

#clean:
#   rm -rf HypeRvieW
#   find -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
#   find -name "*.d" -exec rm {} \;
#   find -name "*.so" -exec rm {} \;
#   find -name "*.so.*" -exec rm {} \;
    #find -name "*.a" -exec xargs rm {} \;
#   rm -f main/headers/tipo_datos.h

mainCopy_aux:
    if [ ! -d "./$(DIR)" ]; then cp hrw/hrw.h main/include;     cp matlab/matlab.h main/include; cp rawm/rawm.h main/include; cp tiff/tiff.h main/include; cp img_format/img_format.h main/include; cp global_data/global_data.h main/include; mkdir -p main/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/*.* main/dlib; cp database.json $(DIR); fi

#mainCopy:
#   cp hrw/hrw.h main/include
#   cp matlab/matlab.h main/include
#   cp rawm/rawm.h main/include
#   cp tiff/tiff.h main/include
#   cp img_format/img_format.h main/include
#   cp global_data/global_data.h main/include
#   mkdir -p main/dlib
#   cp $(DIR)/dlib/*.* main/dlib
#   #cp libs/*.* $(DIR)/dlib
#   cp database.json $(DIR)

ayuda.o: main/ayuda.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/ayuda.o.d -o main/ayuda.o main/ayuda.c

#classification

classification.o: main/classification/classification.c
    cp global_data/global_data.h main/include
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/classification.o.d -o main/classification/classification.o main/classification/classification.c

gtk-diagram.o: main/classification/gtk-diagram.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/gtk-diagram.o.d -o main/classification/gtk-diagram.o main/classification/gtk-diagram.c

gtk-plugin.o: main/classification/gtk-plugin.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/gtk-plugin.o.d -o main/classification/gtk-plugin.o main/classification/gtk-plugin.c

gtk-pin.o: main/classification/gtk-pin.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/gtk-pin.o.d -o main/classification/gtk-pin.o main/classification/gtk-pin.c

gtk-connection.o: main/classification/gtk-connection.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/gtk-connection.o.d -o main/classification/gtk-connection.o main/classification/gtk-connection.c

gtk-context-menu.o: main/classification/gtk-context-menu.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/gtk-context-menu.o.d -o main/classification/gtk-context-menu.o main/classification/gtk-context-menu.c

gtk-notification.o: main/classification/gtk-notification.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/gtk-notification.o.d -o main/classification/gtk-notification.o main/classification/gtk-notification.c

colors.o:
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/colors.o.d -o main/classification/utils/colors.o main/classification/utils/colors.c

dialogUtils.o: main/classification/utils/dialogUtils.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/dialogUtils.o.d -o main/classification/utils/dialogUtils.o main/classification/utils/dialogUtils.c

progressbar.o: main/classification/utils/progressbar.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/progressbar.o.d -o main/classification/utils/progressbar.o main/classification/utils/progressbar.c

# strings.o:
# $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/strings.o.d -o main/classification/utils/strings.o main/classification/utils/strings.c
#
# styles.o:
# $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/styles.o.d -o main/classification/utils/styles.o main/classification/utils/styles.c
#
# types.o:
# $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/types.o.d -o main/classification/utils/types.o main/classification/utils/types.c

utilFunctions.o: main/classification/utils/utilFunctions.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/utils/utilFunctions.o.d -o main/classification/utils/utilFunctions.o main/classification/utils/utilFunctions.c

#helpers
eventHelper.o: main/classification/helpers/eventHelper.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/helpers/eventHelper.o.d -o main/classification/helpers/eventHelper.o main/classification/helpers/eventHelper.c

renderHelper.o: main/classification/helpers/renderHelper.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/helpers/renderHelper.o.d -o main/classification/helpers/renderHelper.o main/classification/helpers/renderHelper.c

#fileSystem
fileSystem.o: main/classification/fileSystem/fileSystem.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/fileSystem/fileSystem.o.d -o main/classification/fileSystem/fileSystem.o main/classification/fileSystem/fileSystem.c

openHelper.o: main/classification/fileSystem/openHelper.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/fileSystem/openHelper.o.d -o main/classification/fileSystem/openHelper.o main/classification/fileSystem/openHelper.c

saveHelper.o: main/classification/fileSystem/saveHelper.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/fileSystem/saveHelper.o.d -o main/classification/fileSystem/saveHelper.o main/classification/fileSystem/saveHelper.c

#execution
execute.o: main/classification/execution/execute.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/execution/execute.o.d -o main/classification/execution/execute.o main/classification/execution/execute.c

executeHelper.o: main/classification/execution/executeHelper.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/classification/execution/executeHelper.o.d -o main/classification/execution/executeHelper.o main/classification/execution/executeHelper.c

# clasificacion.o:
#   cp global_data/global_data.h main/include
#   $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/clasificacion.o.d -o main/clasificacion.o main/clasificacion.c

common_functions.o: main/common_functions.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/common_functions.o.d -o main/common_functions.o main/common_functions.c

ground_truth.o: main/ground_truth.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/ground_truth.o.d -o main/ground_truth.o main/ground_truth.c

histogram.o: main/histogram.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/histogram.o.d -o main/histogram.o main/histogram.c

image.o: main/image.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/image.o.d -o main/image.o main/image.c

interface_plugins.o: main/interface_plugins.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/interface_plugins.o.d -o main/interface_plugins.o main/interface_plugins.c

main.o: main/main.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/main.o.d -o main/main.o main/main.c

manage_files.o: main/manage_files.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/manage_files.o.d -o main/manage_files.o main/manage_files.c

md5.o: main/md5.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/md5.o.d -o main/md5.o main/md5.c

manage_plugin.o: main/manage_plugin.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/manage_plugin.o.d -o main/manage_plugin.o main/manage_plugin.c

color.o: main/color.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/color.o.d -o main/color.o main/color.c

editor_ground_truth.o: main/editor_ground_truth.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/editor_ground_truth.o.d -o main/editor_ground_truth.o main/editor_ground_truth.c

editor_segmented_image.o: main/editor_segmented_image.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/editor_segmented_image.o.d -o main/editor_segmented_image.o main/editor_segmented_image.c

menu.o: main/menu.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/menu.o.d -o main/menu.o main/menu.c

signals.o: main/signals.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/signals.o.d -o main/signals.o main/signals.c

window.o: main/window.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/window.o.d -o main/window.o main/window.c

biophysical.o: main/biophysical_indexes.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(MODULE_EXPORT_CFLAGS) $(LIBGLADE_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF main/biophysical.o.d -o main/biophysical.o main/biophysical_indexes.c

start_aux:
    if [ ! -d "./$(DIR)" ]; then mkdir -p $(DIR);   mkdir -p $(DIR)/dlib; mkdir -p $(DIR)/image; cp main/image/*.* $(DIR)/image; mkdir -p $(DIR)/image/manual; cp main/image/manual/*.* $(DIR)/image/manual; mkdir -p $(DIR)/image/icons; cp main/image/icons/*.* $(DIR)/image/icons; mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/; mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/compilados; cp -a glade/. $(DIR)/plugins; mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/input; mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/output; printf '# Ignore everything in this directory\n*\n# Except this file\n!.gitignore\n' > $(DIR)/plugins/output/.gitignore; else rm -Rf $(DIR)/plugins/es; rm -Rf $(DIR)/plugins/en; fi

#start:
#   if [ -d "./$(DIR)" ]; then rm -R $(DIR);    fi
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/dlib
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/image
#   cp main/image/*.* $(DIR)/image
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/image/manual
#   cp main/image/manual/*.* $(DIR)/image/manual
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/image/icons
#   cp main/image/icons/*.* $(DIR)/image/icons
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/compilados
#   cp -a glade/. $(DIR)/plugins
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/input
#   mkdir -p $(DIR)/plugins/output
#   printf '# Ignore everything in this directory\n*\n# Except this file\n!.gitignore\n' > $(DIR)/plugins/output/.gitignore

    # Compilamos la librería global_data
global_data.so: global_data.o imaxes.o algoritmo.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so global_data/global_data.o rexistrado/imaxes.o rexistrado/algoritmo.o $(GTK_LIB) -shared -fPIC -lfftw3

global_data.o: global_data/global_data.c
    $(CC) -c -g $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF global_data/global_data.o.d -o global_data/global_data.o global_data/global_data.c -lfftw3

    #Compilamos librería HRW
libhrw.so: hrw.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/dlib/libhrw.so hrw/hrw.o -Ldlib $(GLIB_LIB) -L./hrw/dlib/ -lglobal_data -lz -lm -shared -fPIC

hrw.o: hrw/hrw.c
    mkdir -p hrw/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so hrw/dlib/libglobal_data.so; mkdir -p hrw/include
    $(CC) -c -g -I./hrw/include $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF hrw/hrw.o.d -o hrw/hrw.o hrw/hrw.c

    # Compilamos librería img_format
libimg_format.so: img_format.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/dlib/libimg_format.so img_format/img_format.o -Ldlib $(GLIB_LIB) -L./img_format/dlib/ -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

img_format.o: img_format/img_format.c
    mkdir -p img_format/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so img_format/dlib/libglobal_data.so; mkdir -p img_format/include
    $(CC) -c -g -I./img_format/include $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF img_format/img_format.o.d -o img_format/img_format.o img_format/img_format.c

    # Compilamos librería matlab
libmatlab.so: matlab.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/dlib/libmatlab.so matlab/matlab.o -Ldlib $(GLIB_LIB) $(LIBMATIO_LIB) -L./matlab/dlib/ -lglobal_data -lm -lz -ldl -shared -fPIC

matlab.o: matlab/matlab.c
    mkdir -p matlab/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so matlab/dlib/libglobal_data.so; mkdir -p matlab/include
    $(CC) -c -g -Imatlab/include $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF matlab/matlab.o.d -o matlab/matlab.o matlab/matlab.c

    # Compilamos librería rawm
librawm.so: parson.o rawm.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/dlib/librawm.so rawm/parson.o rawm/rawm.o -Ldlib $(GLIB_LIB)  -L./rawm/dlib/ -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

rawm.o: rawm/rawm.c
    $(CC) -c -g -Irawm/include $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rawm/rawm.o.d -o rawm/rawm.o rawm/rawm.c

parson.o: rawm/parson.c
    mkdir -p rawm/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so rawm/dlib/libglobal_data.so; mkdir -p rawm/include
    $(CC) -c -g -Irawm/include $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rawm/parson.o.d -o rawm/parson.o rawm/parson.c

    # Compilamos plugin ELM
libelm: elm_d.o libreriaFunciones.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libelm elm/elm_d.o elm/libreriaFunciones.o -Ldlib $(GTK_LIB) -L./elm/dlib/ -lglobal_data -fopenmp -L./elm/dlib/ -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -lgfortran -shared -fPIC

elm_d.o: elm/elm_d.c
    mkdir -p elm/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so elm/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF elm/elm_d.o.d -o elm/elm_d.o elm/elm_d.c

libreriaFunciones.o: elm/libreriaFunciones.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF elm/libreriaFunciones.o.d -o elm/libreriaFunciones.o elm/libreriaFunciones.c

   # compilamos plugin PCA-EMP
libpca_emp: pca_emp.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libpca_emp pca_emp/pca_emp.o -Ldlib $(GTK_LIB) -L./pca_emp/dlib/ -lglobal_data -fopenmp -L./pca_emp/dlib/ -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -lgfortran -shared -fPIC

pca_emp.o: pca_emp/pca_emp.c
    mkdir -p pca_emp/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so pca_emp/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF pca_emp/pca_emp.o.d -o pca_emp/pca_emp.o pca_emp/pca_emp.c

   # compilamos plugin PCA
libpca: pca1.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libpca pca/pca1.o -Ldlib $(GTK_LIB) -L./pca/dlib/ -lglobal_data -fopenmp -L./pca/dlib/ -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -lgfortran -shared -fPIC

pca1.o: pca/pca.c
    mkdir -p pca/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so pca/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF pca/pca1.o.d -o pca/pca1.o pca/pca.c

    # Compilamos plugin Rexistrado
librexistrado: rexistrado_d.o imaxes.o algoritmo.o hiperspectral.o pca.o hyfm
    cp rexistrado/tipo_datos.h main/headers/
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libregistration rexistrado/imaxes.o rexistrado/algoritmo.o rexistrado/hiperspectral.o rexistrado/pca.o rexistrado/pca_HYFM.o rexistrado/reg_HYFM.o rexistrado/rexistrado_d.o -Ldlib $(GTK_LIB) $(FFTW3_CFLAGS) -L./rexistrado/dlib/ -lglobal_data -fopenmp -L./rexistrado/dlib/ -llapacke -llapack -lblas -O3 -lm -Ldlib -lfftw3 -lgfortran -shared -fPIC

imaxes.o: rexistrado/imaxes.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/imaxes.o.d -o rexistrado/imaxes.o rexistrado/imaxes.c

algoritmo.o: rexistrado/algoritmo.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/algoritmo.o.d -o rexistrado/algoritmo.o rexistrado/algoritmo.c

hiperspectral.o: rexistrado/hiperspectral.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/hiperspectral.o.d -o rexistrado/hiperspectral.o rexistrado/hiperspectral.c

pca.o: rexistrado/pca.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -lopenblas -O3 -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath=dlib -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/pca.o.d -o rexistrado/pca.o rexistrado/pca.c

hyfm: rexistrado/pca_HYFM.c rexistrado/reg_HYFM.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -lm -llapacke -lblas -lgfortran -O3 -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath=dlib -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/pca_HYFM.o.d -o rexistrado/pca_HYFM.o rexistrado/pca_HYFM.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -lm -O3 -Wl,-rpath=dlib -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/reg_HYFM.o.d -o rexistrado/reg_HYFM.o rexistrado/reg_HYFM.c

rexistrado_d.o: rexistrado/rexistrado_d.c
    mkdir -p rexistrado/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so rexistrado/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rexistrado/rexistrado_d.o.d -o rexistrado/rexistrado_d.o rexistrado/rexistrado_d.c

    # Compilamos plugin rqs
librqs: Image.o RCMG-CPU.o quickshift_cpu.o rqs.o
    $(CPLUS) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/librqs rqs/Image.o rqs/RCMG-CPU.o rqs/quickshift_cpu.o rqs/rqs.o -L./dlib $(GTK_LIB) -fopenmp -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -DUNIX -I. -L./rqs/dlib/ -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

Image.o: rqs/Image.cpp
    mkdir -p rqs/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so rqs/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libimg_format.so rqs/dlib
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rqs/Image.o.d -o rqs/Image.o rqs/Image.cpp

RCMG-CPU.o: rqs/RCMG-CPU.cpp
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rqs/RCMG-CPU.o.d -o rqs/RCMG-CPU.o rqs/RCMG-CPU.cpp

quickshift_cpu.o: rqs/quickshift_cpu.cpp
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rqs/quickshift_cpu.o.d -o rqs/quickshift_cpu.o rqs/quickshift_cpu.cpp

rqs.o: rqs/rqs.cpp
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF rqs/rqs.o.d -o rqs/rqs.o rqs/rqs.cpp

    # Compilamos plugin svm
libsvmPredict:svm-predict.o svm-train.o svm.o svmPrediction.o
    $(CPLUS) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libsvmPredict svm/svm-predict.o svm/svm-train.o svm/svm.o svm/svmPrediction.o -L./svm/dlib $(GTK_LIB) -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

svm-predict.o: svm/svm-predict.c
    mkdir -p svm/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so svm/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF svm/svm-predict.o.d -o svm/svm-predict.o svm/svm-predict.c

svm-train.o: svm/svm-train.c
    $(CC) -c -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed -I/usr/include $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF svm/svm-train.o.d -o svm/svm-train.o svm/svm-train.c

svm.o: svm/svm.cpp
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I. $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF svm/svm.o.d -o svm/svm.o svm/svm.cpp

svmPrediction.o: svm/svmPrediction.cpp
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I. $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF svm/svmPrediction.o.d -o svm/svmPrediction.o svm/svmPrediction.cpp

    # Compilamos plugin watershed
libwatershed:CA-WSHED.o RCMG-CPU1.o watershed.o
    $(CPLUS) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libwatershed watershed/CA-WSHED.o watershed/RCMG-CPU.o watershed/watershed.o -Lwatershed/dlib $(GTK_LIB) -fopenmp -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

CA-WSHED.o: watershed/CA-WSHED.cpp
    mkdir -p watershed/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so watershed/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libimg_format.so watershed/dlib
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF watershed/CA-WSHED.o.d -o watershed/CA-WSHED.o watershed/CA-WSHED.cpp

RCMG-CPU1.o: watershed/RCMG-CPU.cpp
    $(CPLUS) -c -g -I./ $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF watershed/RCMG-CPU.o.d -o watershed/RCMG-CPU.o watershed/RCMG-CPU.cpp

watershed.o: watershed/watershed.c
    $(CC) -c -g $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF watershed/watershed.o.d -o watershed/watershed.o watershed/watershed.c

    # Compilamos el plugin majority voting watershed
libmajorityv_watershed:majorityVoteWatershed.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libmajorityv_watershed mv_w/majorityVoteWatershed.o -L./mv_w/dlib $(GK_LIB) -fopenmp -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

majorityVoteWatershed.o: mv_w/majorityVoteWatershed.c
    mkdir -p mv_w/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so mv_w/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libimg_format.so mv_w/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF mv_w/majorityVoteWatershed.o.d -o mv_w/majorityVoteWatershed.o mv_w/majorityVoteWatershed.c

    # Compilamos el plugin Smoothing
libsmoothing:smoothing.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libsmoothing smoothing/smoothing.o -L./smoothing/dlib $(GK_LIB) -fopenmp -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

smoothing.o: smoothing/smoothing.c
    mkdir -p smoothing/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so smoothing/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF smoothing/smoothing.o.d -o smoothing/smoothing.o smoothing/smoothing.c

    # Compilamos el plugin Denoising
libdenoising:denoising.o
    $(CPLUS) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libdenoising denoising/denoising.o -L./denoising/dlib $(GK_LIB) -fopenmp -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

denoising.o: denoising/denoising.cpp
    mkdir -p denoising/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so denoising/dlib
    $(CPLUS) -c -g $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF denoising/denoising.o.d -o denoising/denoising.o denoising/denoising.cpp


    # Compilamos el plugin majority voting RQS
libmajorityv_rqs:majorityVoteRQS.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/libmajorityv_rqs mv_rqs/majorityVoteRQS.o -L./mv_rqs/dlib $(GK_LIB) -fopenmp -lglobal_data -shared -fPIC

majorityVoteRQS.o: mv_rqs/majorityVoteRQS.c
    mkdir -p mv_rqs/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libglobal_data.so mv_rqs/dlib; cp $(DIR)/dlib/libimg_format.so mv_rqs/dlib
    $(CC) -c -g $(GTK_CFLAGS) -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF mv_rqs/majorityVoteRQS.o.d -o mv_rqs/majorityVoteRQS.o mv_rqs/majorityVoteRQS.c

# Compiles TIFF library
tiff.o: tiff/tiff.c
    $(CC) -Wl,-rpath=dlib -c -g -I./main/include $(GLIB_CFLAGS) -ltiff -o tiff/tiff.o tiff/tiff.c

end:
    cp -a $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/. $(DIR)/plugins/es
    cp -a $(DIR)/plugins/compilados/. $(DIR)/plugins/en
```

I put several dependencies in order to force make to only compile when a file has changed. However make is compiling everything every time I run.
Is there a way I can modify it to only compile the files that have been modified?
Running make will always trigger a full recompile, even if nothing has changed. None of the files have changed, so why is it doing this?

Comment: There are better ways of writing makefiles: [here](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/) is a very reasonable overview. Also, normally shared libraries do not belong in a dependency list, unless you also build them in the same make run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The way to do it is to follow the [second rule of makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).

Your rules say you will build a file such as `gtk-connection.o`.  But what the recipes in your rules actually *do* is build a file such as `main/classification/gtk-connection.o`.  You are not telling the truth to make, so the next time you run make it looks to see if the file `gtk-connection.o` exists, and it never does, so make always decides to rebuild it.

You need to either change the target of your rule to reflect the actual file you want to be built, or you have to change your recipe to build the file you told make you would build.

In general you really should try to take advantage of make's features for simplifying makefiles such as pattern rules, automatic variables, etc.